# Does git svn support svn:needs-lock?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

To access our SVN repository I'm using git svn and other team members are using svn.

When they set the needs-lock property it appears that git svn ignores this and allows me to update the files anyway.

Is that accurate?

Also, is it possible to manage the needs-lock property using git svn?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From git-svn documentation under bugs:

> We ignore all SVN properties except svn:executable. Any unhandled
>   properties are logged to $GIT_DIR/svn//unhandled.log

And since `svn:needs-lock` is a communication to the client saying that the file had to be made read only, you cannot achieve this with git-svn.

Answer (score 3):

`git-svn` does not handle this. But you may try to use [SubGit](http://subgit.com/) instead.

Among other things SubGit handles most of `svn:*` properties and Git attributes. It also works on the server side, so one may use any Git client to work with Subversion repository.

For more details you may refer to [SubGit documentation](http://subgit.com/documentation/) and comparison with [git-svn](http://subgit.com/documentation/gitsvn.html).